# Should I let the committee know that they accidentally mentioned two deadlines for a job application?

Tags: job-search, job

I applied for a tenure track job recently. There were two deadlines mentioned in their advertisement (on mathjobs), one was Oct 1 and the other was Oct 15. I did not notice the Oct 1st one and applied on Oct 15. I never received a call from them, so out of curiosity, I looked at their job ad and found out about the two deadlines. Can I email the hiring committee chair and let them know about this situation and ask whether or not my application is being considered? If so, what would be the appropriate language? I do not want to come across as someone who wants to take advantage of it. I genuinely overlooked the earlier deadline.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just ask, saying that you noticed two deadlines listed but only after you applied by the second one. Ask if there is any problem with your application because of this.

A short email is really all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the search chair has already received 30 emails about their typo.    Reminding them of their mistake is unlikely to benefit you.  Do not email.

Comment: This is certainly correct... though, it's not clear to any of us whether the questioner's situation will be altered because of it.

Comment: @paulgarrett, actually it is terrible advice. The reason for writing isn't to inform them, but to seek their assurance that you are under consideration. If they get 30 emails it is their own fault and they can easily stop the flood by simply informing everyone applying during the interim period of their status. They should have done so after the first email. The only way this advice could be "correct" here is if other people don't do this. If everyone takes it, then no one informs the institution.

Comment: @Buffy, yes, _if_ everyone were to take this advice, it wouldn't be good. That's not quite an argument for _no_ one taking the advice. Hard to know, I think.

Comment: @Buffy I see no value in "assurances."

Answer (score 1):

You can send an email but I suggest to put effort for searching other positions that are currently open and accept applications, instead of trying to recover the one that probably would lead to dead end. I don't wanna be so pessimistic but you should become used to not hearing back from whatever job that you applied regardless of if your application is strong or weak, or if it is submitted within deadline or not, or it has all the required documentation or not, etc. Unfortunately it's the way it works for pretty much everyone these days inside/outside of academia.